# Cannot interact with Partitioned Tables in GridDB

Tags: griddb

I have a partitioned table made with the GridDB CLI, but when I try to interact with it via Python
NoSQL, it results in an error:

```
gs[public]> showcontainer myIntervalPartition4
Database : public
Name : myIntervalPartition4
Type : COLLECTION
Partition ID: 19
DataAffinity: -
Partitioned : true
Partition Type : INTERVAL
Partition Column : date
Partition Interval Value : 30
Partition Interval Unit : DAY
Expiration Type : PARTITION
Expiration Time : 30
Expiration Time Unit : DAY
Columns:
No Name Type CSTR RowKey
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0 date TIMESTAMP(3) NN
1 value STRING
```

And then some python code (using python 3.10 on Ubuntu 22.04

```
import griddb_python as griddb
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
factory = griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()
DB_HOST = "127.0.0.1:10001"
DB_CLUSTER = "myCluster"
DB_USER = "admin"
DB_PASS = "admin"
try:
# (1) Connect to GridDB
# Fixed list method
gridstore = factory.get_store(
notification_member=DB_HOST, cluster_name=DB_CLUSTER, username=DB_USER,
password=DB_PASS)
container_name = "myIntervalPartition4"
partition_container = gridstore.get_container(container_name)
print("Succesfully connected to GridDB!")
if partition_container == None:
print("ERROR Container not found: " + container_name)
query = partition_container.query("SELECT *")
rs = query.fetch()
while rs.has_next():
row = rs.next()
print(row)
except griddb.GSException as e:
for i in range(e.get_error_stack_size()):
print("[", i, "]")
print(e.get_error_code(i))
print(e.get_location(i))
print(e.get_message(i))
```

Succesfully connected to GridDB!
ERROR Container not found: myIntervalPartition4